# Compare the complexity of two algorithms given steps

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

Assume you had a data set of size n and two algorithms that processed that data
set in the same way. Algorithm A took 10 steps to process each item in the data set. Algorithm B processed each item in 100 steps. What would the complexity
be of these two algorithms?

I have drawn from the question that algorithm A completes the processing of each item with 1/10th the complexity of algorithm B,and using the graph provided in the accepted answer from the question: [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation) I am concluding that algorithm B has a complexity of O(n^2) and algorithm A a complexity of O(n), but am struggling to make conclusions beyond that without the implementation.

Comment: Using only a single benchmark of 10 steps for A and 100 steps for B, we cannot conclude the complexity.  However, if, for example, you had another point of 25 steps for A and 625 steps for B, then it might support your conclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need more than one data point before you can start making any conclusions about time complexity. The difference of 10 steps and 100 steps between Algorithm A and Algorithm B could be for many different reasons:

1. Additive Constant difference: Algorithm A is always 90 steps faster than Algorithm B no matter the input. In this case, both algorithms would have the same time complexity.
2. Scalar Multiplicative difference: Algorithm A is always 10 times faster than Algorithm B no matter the input. In this case, both algorithms would have the same time complexity.
3. The case that you brought up, where B is O(n^2) and A is O(n)
4. Many, many other possibilities.